# Warning about system root certificate pool crypto/x509

Tags: docker

I am having the following warning message when issueing docker commands: (ex: docker ps)

```
C:\Users\whha>docker ps
time="2017-01-24T23:17:36+01:00" level=warning msg="Unable to use system      certificate pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows"
```

Any idea how can it be avoided?
I´m running docker using docker toolbox on windows 8.1.

Comment: see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30450

Answer (score 7):

Installing the last available version solved the problem for me (https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases) :

BEFORE

```
minux@DESKTOP-OCQQ65T MINGW64 /c
$ docker --version
time="2017-04-05T17:56:55+02:00" level=info msg="Unable to use system 
certificate pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows"
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
```

AFTER

```
minux@DESKTOP-OCQQ65T MINGW64 /c
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.04.0-ce-rc2, build 2f35d73
```

Comment: Not for me. I started with the most recent stable version. :/

Answer (score 4):

I started having this problem today after updating to the docker toolbox version 1.13.1 of Docker Toolbox for windows.

Checking around the internet, and saw a github issue that this problem can't be fixed for windows. 
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/422

Hence, probably has to follow @mayur_patil's suggestion to roll back to 1.12.x version. FYI, previous release can be found here: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases

Answer (score 2):

I have installed docker toolbox version 1.13.1 for windows.
OS : Windows 10 Enterprise.
I solved the same issue with the v 1.12.6 instead 1.13.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can change version series.

I was getting this error on Docker-toolbox 1.13.1

After that I downgraded to 1.12.2 and my problem solved.

OS: Windows 7 SP1

Check out and reply.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and solved it by download v1.12.6 from:

https://github.com/docker/toolbox/releases